# Render control in multiple places

Tags: wpf

Is there any way to show same control partially in more then one place in WPF? Such feature is implemented in Microsoft Office Excel, where you can split current workspace in two duplicates.

[image]

I know, controls cannot have two parents, but may be some solution like rendering control to second parent space and emulating of input events exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `UserControl`s share one view model. I guess such controls in Office products are not rendering an identical instance at multiple places.

Comment: I cannot use same view model for two controls, cos it leads to heavy overhead, I just need to show part of a control on another, without data manipulation

Comment: That's not possible, as far as I know. You'll have to extract the parts of view and viewmodel you want to "duplicate", put them in a separate UserControl (maybe with its own smaller viewmodel, nested inside the bigger one), and then reuse that UserControl both in your old view and in your other control, bound to the same data.

Comment: Am successfully has rendered part of control, but hasn't found a way to reroute all input events, so you are right.